# $ \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left\vert x\right\vert ^{n-2}u\left( x\right) =0. $ Show that $u\equiv0$ in $B_{1}\left( 0\right) $.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Let $n\geq3$, $B_{1}\left(  0\right)  \subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $u\in
C\left(  \overline{B_{1}\left(  0\right)  }\backslash\left\{  0\right\}
\right)  $ be harmonic. Suppose $u\left(  x\right)  =0$ on $\partial
B_{1}\left(  0\right)  $ and
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left\vert x\right\vert ^{n-2}u\left(  x\right)  =0.
$$
Show that $u\equiv0$ in $B_{1}\left(  0\right)  $. (Hint: Compare $u$ with
some radially symmetric harmonic function.)

I am unable to solve the problem. In fact, I am not getting any direction on where to start. The function is not harmonic in the unit ball, it is harmonic on the punctured disc. So, I cannot use the mean value theorem. The function is not even defined at $0$. If someone can even give me a starting point with some more direction with hints. I will be grateful and I will try to fill up the details.

Comment: Hint: What is $$\Delta\left(\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}\right)$$ for $n \geq 3$ ? (it is not zero)

Comment: This is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2809806/42969.