# Determine all positive harmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

If u is a positive harmonic function on $\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}$, show that there exists a,b which is non-negative, such that

$$u(x)=a+b|x|^{2-n}\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}$$

Thanks for your concentration. This is a problem from Yau-contest. I try to use Liouville Theorem, however I don't know where to begin.
Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: $|x|^{2-n}$ is a fundamental solution of Laplace equation in $R^n$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341370/fundamental-solution-to-the-poisson-equation-by-fourier-transform or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099027/computations-problem-with-reverse-fourier-transform/4099754#4099754

Comment: the foundamental solution is $\frac{1}{n(2-n)w_{n}|x|^{n-2}}$, however, how to apply? @Svyatoslav

Comment: What's Yau contest?

Comment: One Math Competition for College Students, however this is not important, how to deal with this problem? @Calvin Khor

Comment: [I found the question](http://yau-contest.com/en/page-rule.html), 2018 past exam paper, Analysis and Differential Equations Individual, question 6. There is a partial result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809806/removable-singularity-for-harmonic-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I found the full proof. It is quite long, you may check sections 3.9 - 3.14 of [this book](https://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf) on Harmonic functions. The result is called Bôcher's Theorem (or rather, it is a corollary of it.) That book cites [this paper](https://www.axler.net/Bocher.pdf) as the source of the proof.

Comment: @Calvin Khor, Thank you every much!